# Change popover position when affix

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

What I want to do is when affix is set I want to change the popover position to bottom what I did is this:

```
 $('.gallery-holder').on('affix.bs.affix', function (e) {
  console.log('check');

  $(this).find('.popover').popover({
     placement: 'bottom'
  });
})
```

The check works perfect but the position of the popover in `.gallery-holder` is not changing its position

and this is the html:

```
 <div class="gallery-holder affix">
    <label class="price-label">
                    All-in prijs
      <span class="material-icons" data-content="
          <ul class='list-checked'>
              <li>Basishuursom</li>
              <li>Reserveringskosten</li>
              <li>Eindschoonmaak</li>
              <li>Lokale heffingen</li>
          </ul>
          <p>Boek je een vakantiehuis of vakantietent?</p>
          <p>Ontvang gratis de <a href='/vakantiepark/park/attractiepas'>AttractiePas</a>!</p>
                        " data-placement="auto top" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus" tabindex="0" title="" data-original-title="Alle prijzen zijn inclusief:">
                        help
      </span>
   </label>
</div>
```

here is a [LINK](http://www.bootply.com/Dvz4DdYswp) to a bootlpy, as you can see it is triggered to a top placement and it stays at top when the `affix.bs.affix` is triggered

Comment: Can you attach some demo snippet?

Comment: @user3041764 check updated question

Comment: If you change the selector in your function to target the initialising element instead of the popover itself, it should work - I tested the following locally: `$(this).find("[data-toggle='popover']").popover({placement: 'bottom'});`

Comment: @fridge_light why is this not working in my bootply

Comment: It was more complicated than I thought. The issue seems to be that you have to assign the popover properties when `affix.bs.affix` is fired *and* when `affix-top.bs.affix` is fired. It's simpler to just check the status of the navbar whenever the popover is triggered, which only requires one function - I'll post a working example in a bit.

Comment: Please see the Bootply at http://www.bootply.com/dNDj85TQVg.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can dynamically assign the position of a popover simply and reliably using the `function` call built into the `placement` option. Every time the popover is triggered, you can evaluate the status of the navbar (fixed or not) and then make the relevant assignment of `top` or `bottom`.

With reference to the Bootply you posted, this is the only JavaScript needed:

```
$('[data-toggle=popover]').popover({placement: function() {
        if($('.navbar-inverse').hasClass('affix-top')) {
            // console.log('top');                    
            return 'top';
        }
        else {
            // console.log('bottom');
            return 'bottom';
        }
    }                
});
```

You can find a working example here: http://www.bootply.com/dNDj85TQVg.

Please note that when you're handling a popover in this way, you should target the initialising element and not the popover itself (so not `.popover`, which Bootstrap adds dynamically). For this example I used the `data-toggle` attribute, but in cases where you may end up with more than one popover, an ID or class would be more suitable as a selector.

Comment: Thanks a lot you helped me out on this!